# ORDER BY separately positive & negative numbers in MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table and would like to return the rows based on a column value in this order:

- First ascending order if the column >=0
- Then descending order if the column <0

E.g. 0,2,4,7,-2,-3,-5

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can use [SIGN](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-sign-function.php) to sort the positive numbers to the top, then take the absolute value with [ABS](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-abs-function.php) to get the desired ASC/DESC.

```
SELECT * FROM theTable
ORDER BY SIGN(col) DESC, ABS(col)
```

**EDIT**

As Nahuel pointed out, the above will sort 0's to the middle between positive and negative.  To instead group them with the positives, you can use a `CASE` instead (or, if your column is only integers, the slightly magical `SIGN(col + 1)`)

```
SELECT * FROM theTable
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN col >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
    ABS(col)
```

Comment: +1 because it's more concise, but maybe a problem with 0. order by case when col>=0 then 1 else 2 end, abs(col)

Comment: Ah yes, missed that 0 needs to come at the beginning, not between positive and negative.  Will update

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT columnName1 FROM Tbl
WHERE columnName1 >= 0
ORDER BY columnName1 ASC

UNION

SELECT columnName1 FROM Tbl
WHERE columnName1 < 0
ORDER BY columnName1 DESC
```

Should work