# How to Order data which have + and - value

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data in one field like this.

Name:   Rate
A :      +1.05
B :      +1.95
C :      +0.50
D :      -1.25
E :      -0.35
F :      -1.50

But When order by rate DESC
I am getting like this.

Name:   Rate
B  :     +1.95
A  :     +1.05
C  :     +0.50
**D  :     -1.25**
**E  :     -0.35**
F  :     -1.50

But It should be or I want to like this

Name:   Rate
B  :     +1.95
A  :     +1.05
C  :     +0.50
**E  :     -0.35**
**D  :     -1.25**
F  :     -1.50

Please help

Comment: Perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282571/specific-order-by-in-mysql-statement .. Wait, no, you only have one coloumn, right? Also, if it's varchar, I would suggest you to either separate coloumns or to store values in different formats

Comment: @briosheje This is not anything like that question.

Comment: @Barmar: isn't it? he is trying to sort values about their sign first. Just take an inspiration from the link above, I didn't say "It's the solution".

Comment: In that question he wants to sort negative and positive numbers in opposite order. This question wants to sort all numbers in descending order.

Comment: I can't figure out how you're getting the order you're getting. It's not numeric or lexicographic order. Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: what is the datatype for rate in the database since it does not look like float() and in that case the sorting should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution is adding new column which is store plus or minus flag, then you can do it easliy, if minus order it ascending else order it descending

```
select * from tablename where type='+' order by value desc
union
select * from tablename where type='-' order by value asc
```

something like that