# How to sort datatype tiny int in mysql

Tags: mysql

what i need

- i need to sort the integer numbers in mysql.

unsubscribe tinyint(6)

1, 1, 4, 5,1,1,...etc

sql query

```
 SELECT e0_.metadata AS metadata0, u1_.unsubscribe AS unsubscribe1, u1_.id AS id2, u1_.linkedin_id AS linkedin_id3, u1_.facebook_id AS facebook_id4, u1_.linkedin_profile AS linkedin_profile5, u1_.profile AS profile6, 
    CASE WHEN u1_.linkedin_id <> ''
    OR u1_.facebook_id <> ''
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END AS sclr7, 
    CASE WHEN e0_.edition =23932
    THEN 'current'
    ELSE 'past'
    END AS sclr8
    FROM event_visitor e0_, user u1_
    WHERE e0_.user = u1_.id
    AND e0_.event =25162
    AND e0_.published =1
    AND e0_.showme =1
    GROUP BY e0_.user
    ORDER BY sclr7 DESC , e0_.id DESC , LENGTH( u1_.unsubscribe ) 
    LIMIT 30
```

- solution i  tried.

  1. length
  2. cast
  3. order by col *1 ,col

but no solution is working in tiny int datatype.

problem

- there is also negative number like -5.

o/p should be

```
all 1 should be at top .
```

finally after googling a lot

- ORDER BY CAST(est_dily_pple as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC
- ORDER BY CAST( u1_.unsubscribe AS SIGNED INTEGER ) ASC , sclr7 DESC , e0_.id DESC

  - but problem o/p -5,1,1,..an so on .

Solution i came up:

- ORDER BY SIGN( CAST( u1_.unsubscribe AS SIGNED INTEGER ) ) ASC , ABS( CAST( u1_.unsubscribe AS SIGNED INTEGER ) ) , sclr7 DESC , e0_.id DESC .

Refrence

```
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282571/specific-order-by-in-mysql-statement
```

i need to implement the abs function doctrine

dql code

```
     $from = 'Entities\EventVisitor visitor,Entities\User user';
   $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

  $qb->select("visitor.metadata,ABS( u1_.unsubscribe )as unsubscribe)
 ->add('from',$from)

 ->where('visitor.user=user.id')
 ->groupBy('visitor.user')
->orderBy('unsubscribe','asc')

error 500 internal error.
```

Comment: is `ORDER BY ABS(unsubscribe), unsubscribe` not an option - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1e97ac/3?

Comment: can you help in implemnt abs fucntion in doctrine